# How to check for null values in a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, dataset

This is my code

```
lbltrialval.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("PretrailOrderDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I am getting an error

> "Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a
>   nullable type."

How to check for null values while assigning values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this.

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PretrailOrderDate"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        lbltrialval.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("PretrailOrderDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and this works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lbltrialval.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime?>("PretrailOrderDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("PretrailOrderDate") != System.DBNull.Value)
{
    Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("PretrailOrderDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for `DBNull`:

```
lbltrialval.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PretrailOrderDate"] != DBNull.Value ?
                   Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("PretrailOrderDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PretrailOrderDate"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    //Action to take if null value
}
else
{
    try
    {
        lbltrialval.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]
        .Field<DateTime>("PretrailOrderDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Conversion Error
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```